# Increment by count of group value in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want to have column B autofill the sequential count of the value in column A.

So something like:

```
A   -     B    
10  -     1    
10  -     2    
10  -     3    
20  -     1    
20  -     2    
30  -     1    
30  -     2    
30  -     3    
40  -     1
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Put this formula in B1 and copy drag down:

```
=COUNTIF($A$1:A1,A1)
```

[image]