# Increment by count of group value in Excel Table

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Excel 2016-2021

New to superuser, I couldn't comment on [increment-by-count-of-group-value-in-excel](https://superuser.com/questions/1193337/increment-by-count-of-group-value-in-excel/1193339#1723791) which describes what I intend to do, BUT within an Excel Table.

Say my table has the following content:

[Excel table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MfP2.png)

what's the formula for autoincrementing column [formula with structured ref] using **[structured references](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/using-structured-references-with-excel-tables-f5ed2452-2337-4f71-bed3-c8ae6d2b276e)**?  The formula should automatically apply when users add a new year, which is the case with tables.
By the way, is there a way that the increment remain unchanged if the table is sorted so that year=2019 and increment=1 still references col=a, year-increment being kind of a reliable ID ? Might not be possible but asking!

Comment: Welcome! Sorry, but in the way you describe the task, we are faced with the [**XY problem**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) - neither the way to fill in the table, nor the subsequent use of the calculation results is clear. Yes, the task can be solved, it will require significant efforts, tricks. But why? What are you going to do with the records `{2019-2-b;2020-2-d;2021-1-f}`? Perhaps there is an easier way to solve the main problem.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know the *XY problem* but that table was for the sake of the example. The main question is about the _group by_ and the counting with 'structured references' instead of cell addresses. How to convert **`=COUNTIF($A$1:A1,A1)`** to a more elegant table formula?
For the advanced part of the question, let's say `{2019-1}, {2019-2}`, would be ID (or quick primary keys) of the rows. The question is just technical, that I should do it is a another point!

Comment: Although you could probably create a formula that will start 2019-1 as column a, are the rest allowed to change if items were inserted? For example if you insert 2019-3 do you want 2021-1 to remain f or change to g?

Comment: sorry for not being clear enough. My goal was first to translate `=COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)` as mentioned below by @Lee to _structured references_. Keeping the order while sorting (which I don't think is easily feasible) was another question I shouldn't have asked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first cell:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(INDEX([year],ROW($1:1))=[@year]))
```

or

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(INDEX([year],1):[@year]=[@year]))
```

*See comments below from @jgran.  The first formula apparently does not work properly for that user in Excel 2019, but does in Excel 2021.  The second formula works in both versions*

[image]

Comment: the formula, translated into french Excel version as `=SOMMEPROD(--(INDEX([year];LIGNE($1:1))=[@year]))` brings about `{2019-1}, {2019-1}, {2020-0}, {2020-0}, {2020-0}, {2021-0}` with data from my example.

Comment: @jgran As you can see from the screenshot I just added, I get different results.

Comment: you are correct! I am puzzled and will redo it once again! What happens when you add a new year? Is the [increment] value updated correctly? I noticed it went wrong with `=COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)` when applied in a table. Could you explain a bit the logics behind your formula, please?

Comment: @jgran Add a new year and see.

Comment: @jgran To figure out the logic, I suggest you examine how the formula changes from one row to the next, and also use the formula evaluation tool, paying special attention to the results for the `INDEX` function portion, which returns the rows of the `[year]` column from the first row to the current row.

Comment: Well I had to find an Excel where the formula was working for seeing, it was not lazyness! I could test in an Excel-2021 and the formula worked out. The same file opened in Excel-2019 produced the aforementioned stranged results. For the logics, it's more about `COUNTIF` and `SUMPROD` usage... Sorry, I cannot upvote your answer yet.

Comment: @jgran In the earlier version, try entering the formula as an array formula (using `ctrl+shif+enter`).  Also, you could replace the INDEX function with `INDEX([year],1):[@year]` and get the same results (at least in the later version). Answer edited to show this alternate formula.

Comment: I didn't know about _array formula_. Indeed I had noticed that the formula taken from Excel-2021 was encapsulated with `{..}` when opened in Excel-2019. But it doesn't change the answer and remains wrong. If reproducible maybe mention your answer requires Excel-2021? Thx

Comment: @jgran Ordinarily `SUMPRODUCT` does not require being entered as an array formula, and should work in all versions. Without access, I don't know what is happening in the earlier version.

Comment: The `SUMPRODUCT(--(INDEX([year],1):[@year]=[@year]))` works well as expected in both versions Excel-2019 and Excel-2021.

Comment: @jgran Please try normally entered `=SUMPRODUCT(--(INDEX([year],ROW($1:1),1)=[@year]))` in `2019` (column value added).

Comment: Redone with Excel-2019 and same results: column [increment] is 1 for 2019 and 0 otherwise. Still 1 when few 2019 are added on new rows in the table.

Comment: @jgran Thanks for testing that. I added a caveat to the answer.

Comment: @jgran *The SUMPRODUCT(--(INDEX([year],1):[@year]=[@year])) works well as expected in both versions Excel-2019 and Excel-2021.* Since my answer seems to be what you require, kindly mark it as Accepted.  See [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't click on +1 for your answer so I thought I couldn't do anything due to lack of reputation! I can't comment the original question neither ([increment-by-count-of-group-value-in-excel](https://superuser.com/questions/1193337/increment-by-count-of-group-value-in-excel/1193339#1723791)), but it would be useful to link it to this answer for any reader coming to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

```
=COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)
```

[image]

Comment: That's what I want to achieve indeed, but in an **Excel Table** with _structured references_ like `[year]` or `[@year]`.