# Get max of a column based on another column value dynamically in Excel Table

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Office ≥ 2016

I'm struggling to get the maximum of a column based on the value of another column dynamically in an Excel Table.

Say my table is such:

[image: Excel table example]

If a user adds a new year, increment should be the max increment + 1 for this year, or just 1 for a new year.

```
if new year = 2019, increment should be 11
if new year = 2020, increment should be 46
if new year = 2021, increment should be 66
if new year = 2022, increment should be 1
```

I try to adapt the answer of my own question [increment-by-count-of-group-value-in-excel-table](https://superuser.com/questions/1738503/increment-by-count-of-group-value-in-excel-table/1738503#1723791) which should be close enough I think, but with no success.

Comment: Then why doesn't the 2nd and 3rd rows of 2020 increment by 1? How do you go from 3 to 20, then 45?

Comment: @Reddy good catch! the column [increment] should indeed be a real sequence, but users being users, they will remove some rows based on other criteria leaving a 'sparse sequence'. If all values of the sequence were present, the INDEX would be enough and the answer of my linked question would fit!

Comment: you can try the following formula: `=IFERROR(INDEX( B2:B6, XMATCH(A7,A2:A6,0,-1))+1,1)`

Comment: @Reddy Thanks. Unfortunately XMATCH isn't available in Office 2019 (I hope a solution can work from Excel-2016 on). I am also looking to a formula built on **_structured references_**.

Comment: If users are deleting rows, then a formula will not work. Otherwise, try the `MAXIF()` formula

Comment: @gns100 well in a table with data validation (see [default-value-drop-down-list](https://www.automateexcel.com/how-to/default-value-drop-down-list/)) the formula remains active.
I tried using MAXIF (more exactly MAX(IF(...)), but couldn't make it work appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following formula:

```
=IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/(A2:A6=A7),B2:B6)+1,1)
```

`LOOKUP(2,1/(A2:A6=A7)` finds the latest data equals to A7. 1 is added to the returned value. If no result is returned as lookup value was not found, meaning there is an error, 1 is returned. Adapt the formula to your ranges.

[image]

You can also try the formula below:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(B2:B6,MATCH(2,1/(A2:A6=A7),1))+1,1)
```

Comment: Thanks! I was able to translate your formula into my french Excel(`=SIERREUR(INDEX([increment];EQUIV(2;1/(A2:A6=A7);1))+1;1)`) and it works as you demonstrate it. I cannot translate it into a formula with **structured references** though. You use column [year] except the last row and that challenges me! In fact I wanted the formula to work each time we add a new row to the table. But for it working, formula should be casted to plain values, which doesn't seem possible. Altogether my approach seems wrong.

Comment: @jgran What do you mean by structured references? If you are talking about the ranges, then you should adapt the formula and ranges. Regarding the column Year, based on your image, as people will be filling that that column. The formula can be adapted for more rows. With an `IF` function to check if the year is empty or not. If it is empty, show a blank cell. Something like this: `IF(A7<>"",IFERROR(INDEX(B2:B6,MATCH(2,1/(A2:A6=A7),1))+1,1),""`.

Comment: By structured references, I mean this [using-structured-references-with-excel-tables](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/using-structured-references-with-excel-tables-f5ed2452-2337-4f71-bed3-c8ae6d2b276e), ie using [year], [increment] or [@year] for instance which work inside Excel Table. Thanks for your time, but the recalculation of the formula would produce wrong results, I'm afraid. My initial idea was wrong.